# Concatenate rows in select query (in Advantage Data Architect)

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, string-concatenation, advantage-database-server

How can I concatenate rows in select query? (in Advantage Data Architect)

I tried run the following scripts:

The first script:

```
declare @str string;
set @str = '';
select @str = @str + field_1 from my_table1
```

But I get a result where all rows contain "false", like this picture:

[image]

Second script:

```
declare @str string;
select @str = coalesce(@str + ', ','') + field_1 from my_table1
```

This time, all rows are empty (note: the field from "my_table1" is not null).

Picture:

[image]

I tried to search the solution on the Internet for Advantage Data Architect, but I could not find a solution.

Comment: What is the definition of your table? In particular what data type is the field you are trying to query?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? Please at a clear description of what data you have and what the output should look like.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Sorry for the long answer. Thank you for your answer.
I want to concatenate the result from select query one column. The type of result column is char. In summary, I want to get the string contains result from select query of my column, with separate by any symbol (','). For example - 'result1, result2, result3 ...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL or `string_agg` in Oracle / Postgres.

The general algorithm for that is something like:

```
DECLARE @S STRING;

DECLARE CURSOR C AS 
SELECT
  CONVERT(field_1, SQL_CHAR) AS "val"
FROM 
  my_table1;

OPEN C;

WHILE FETCH C do
  -- Since @S is NULL for the first row this will ensure 
  -- that the result does not start with the separator.
  @S = COALESCE(@S + ', ' + C.val, C.val);
END;

CLOSE C;

SELECT @S;
```

[A general function can be found on the ADS forum.](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/questions/700/how-to-concatenate-values-in-a-column)

PS: This is the reverse of [splitting a string into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352547/splitting-a-string-into-rows/5353369?s=4%7C3.6864#5353369).

Comment: Thank you for your example. I think this solution is good for me.