# Updating to combine values and remove one of them using SQL

Tags: sql, string-concatenation, advantage-database-server

I am using Advantage SQL and the below shown table (if you see the attached Item 5 and 9) you'll see that the EVID is 90, Officer is IQAONE on both, but the Roles are - and T. What I want is to, for any instances that are like this in a real life example, to have the Roles field to be -T (in this example anyway), and to remove the one that's left with the singular Role character. In the long-term, I need this to look at EVID where this is the same, AND PLACE is the same, OFFICER is the same TRIDENT is the same and so on.

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: BTW: Your table is not properly normalized. The roles column violates the first normal form (1NF). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Answer (score 0):

you could perform a delete using a where condition based on the result for the evid with more then a result

```
select from my_table 
where evid in (
  select  evid, count(*)
  from my_table  
  group by evid 
  having count(*) > 1 
) and roles = 'T'
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That might help with the delete part, but I also need to prod in the right direction to merge together the two roles, when the evid and (place or officer or trident or apident) are the same, but with a different Role character so I end up with one record.

Comment: you comment is not clear  you should add  a clear data sample with you actual data and the expected  result .. please don't post image ..post data sample as tabular text ..

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary table with the distinct values for evid, place, officer, trident and all the other fields that should be distinct:

```
SELECT
    MIN(item) AS "item"
  , evid
  , place
  , officer
  , trident
  , SPACE(100) AS "roles"
INTO #tmp
FROM table
GROUP BY
  , evid
  , place
  , officer
  , trident

UPDATE #tmp SET roles = '';
```

In the next step you have to aggregate the roles, since ADS does not have a `STRING_AGG` function you have to do this with cursors, loops, etc.

I have written such code before, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27601329/concatenate-rows-in-select-query-in-advantage-data-architect/27602973#27602973) for example.

You can then just delete the whole original table and insert the data from the temporary table. Ideally I would do these last steps in a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM table;
-- Assuming the table and the temp table have the same exact fields
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM #tmp;

END TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Jens. The #tmp table bit looks to be getting me on the right track, but am struggling a bit with the loop stuff. I know I want to put in my string the concat of roles for combination of evid and (place or officer or trident or apident), but not seeing how just yet. I'll keep trying in meantime though.

Comment: Nope, totally stuck @Jens. Boo

Comment: I'm happy to help, but please write a new question about just the combining part with the code you have tried so far first.